# Access to files outside the Web Environment, soft link; looking for canonical alternative

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, symlink

I have a shared directory using samba on my ubuntu server at this path:

```
/home/user/share/
```

I use it to share some installation software on the intranet, mainly files: msi and exe (for windows end user)...
on the same server I have a web server in the root path like:

```
/var/www/html/
```

but I want to create a link in the OS that can provide an access for php to the shared folder (if I want to distribute the programs as a download on the intranet, since not everyone knows how to access a network disk) and create a web download of the installer (s):

```
ln -s /home/user/share/installer /var/www/html/sl-soft
```

I tried to use a soft link but I get a blank page when I try to navigate.

[image]

**Does anyone have a *canonical* answer that by using php / apache / linux can fix this problem?**

Comment: The place you linked to with the symlink isn't the place you originally mentioned contained the data. Is that deliberate?

Comment: yes, it is really where the data is located ...

Comment: Ok I just wanted to check because `/home/user/share/` was different to `home/share/`... and it's strange that you can't see any files.

Comment: is correct, I can correct it.